# What is considered as a document in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have been learning MongoDB for the past two days and I've been confused with documents and their limits, and how to overcome the limits.

What is a difference between documents and collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of MongoDB, a document means any piece of valid [BSON*](http://bsonspec.org/) (binary JSON). The word does not have the everyday meaning of, say, an MS Word file or PDF.

A collection is a container for zero or more documents. There is no requirement for all documents in a collection to have the same structure. Indeed, that is one of the drivers behind the NoSQL movement. So it would be possible to store a shopping cart, a birth certificate and a recipie for chocolate cake in the same collection. (Though *possible* it would be an exceedingly poor design.) A collection is also the boundary for some management tasks, like copying, and authorisation.

---

* *BSON* is actually an important distinction as there are more data types than [JSON](http://www.json.org/). For example, the default primary key (`_id` field) is an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#description), which doesn't exist as a standard JSON type.

For more context see:

- [Documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/); and
- [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

BSON and MongoDB Extended JSON are JSON-like in terms of document structure, but definitely not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Document in MongoDB is analogous to row in relational database. As opposed to relational database, MongoDB supports dynamic schema i.e. documents can consist of varying fields.

Collection is a set of documents belonging to the same entity similar to tables in relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

Collection can be visualized as a table in RDBMS.

Document can be visualized as a row in RDBMS.

Biggest difference is collection need not have all the fields/columns.

There is no joining of two columns. It is achieved by nested documents.